# "Luck" System for Text Game

Tags: python-3.x

I'm interested in putting a "luck" system within a text game I'm doing for fun. There will be certain if/else statements and the variable will be assigned a number based on the choice the user makes, I want to later add up all the luck later to use in some other statements.

Would I be better off putting each luck if/else dialogue within it's own function and then trying to add all the functions together with a total_luck function later on?

Thinking of something like this at the moment but is this the best approach?

```
def luckquestion_1():
question = input("What will you do? ").lower()
if question in "a":
    return 10
elif question in "b":
    return 4
elif question in "c":
    return 1

def luckquestion_2():
question = input("What will you do? ").lower()
if question in "a":
    return 10
elif question in "b":
    return 4
elif question in "c":
    return 1

def luckquestion_3():
question = input("What will you do? ").lower()
if question in "a":
    return 10
elif question in "b":
    return 4
elif question in "c":
    return 1

luck1 = luckquestion_1()
luck2 = luckquestion_2()
luck3 = luckquestion_3 ()
luck_total = luck1 + luck2 + luck3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the one function & pass in the parameters:

```
def LuckQuestion(questionA, questionB, questionC):
    question = input("What will you do? ").lower()
    if question in questionA:
        return 10
    elif question in questionB:
        return 4
    elif question in questionC:
        return 1

luck1 = LuckQuestion('A', 'B', 'C')
luck2 = LuckQuestion('a', 'b', 'c')
luck3 = LuckQuestion ('1', '2', '3')
luck_total = luck1 + luck2 + luck3
```

This assumes that the return values will be consistent for each luck.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!